# Customizing iTerm. Creating a display profile with Pastel color

Tags: color, iterm

I was trying to follow the instructions given on the page http://kpumuk.info/mac-os-x/customizing-iterm-creating-a-display-profile-with-pastel-colors/

After running the final command when I reopen the iTerm i find that only the background has changed to black and the text to cream color, it doesn't apply variable colors like blue to folders, some red colors for other file types. Please tell me how can I do so. Is there any other thing I can do to have a beautiful programmer's terminal.

Comment: Are you still using iTerm v1? For displaying the output of `ls` with colors, you need to specify the -G argument (or alias it).

Comment: What is the way other programmers do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) if you're looking for a fully-realized lower contrast pastel(-ish) colour scheme. Setting files for iTerm are included in the package.

[image: Solarized Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily customize the color scheme from iTerm's preference. You can manually pick each of the 8 ANSI colors, or choose or import a custom color scheme.

Defining the colors does not automatically colorize all output though. For example to display the output of `ls` with colors you need to add the -G argument: `ls -G`.

You can also alias this to always display colorized output, by for example putting the following in ~/.bash_profile

```
alias ls="ls -G"
```

Comment: can you give some links to cool color schemes, instructions to import them.